# Get the top 3 items of a join

Tags: mysql, join, mariadb, greatest-n-per-group

I have 3 tables:
product, category and product_category (which products are in each category).

I'd like to get the top 3 most expensive product in each category.

I have this basic relation:

```
select c.name
     , p.id
     , p.price 
  from category c
  left 
  join product_category pc
    on pc.category_id = category.id
  left 
  join product p 
    on pc.product_id = p.id
```

But now I would like to get just the 3 most expensive of each category.

In this case we can use any number of joined tables and it can be escalated to any more complex query.

Is this possible without a loop ?

I'm using 10.2.14-MariaDB-log with this schema http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/43035a

Comment: Your query should start from category table in that case.

Comment: changed (edited I mean) ;-)

Comment: Just create a long UNION ALL statement dynamically.

Comment: Can you provide your database schema in a [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/)

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Which MySQL version are you using?

Comment: @RakibulIslam   there you have

Comment: @KamilG. there you have

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get top n records for each group of grouped results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12113699/get-top-n-records-for-each-group-of-grouped-results)

Comment: [_Efficient groupwise max_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/groupwise_max).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL 8.0+ & MariaDB 10.2+ support window functions like `dense_rank` which are suited to handle your case. For each category we assign ranks based on product price and pull only those, who are in the top 3. Use of `dense_rank` properly handles ties which means that if there are products for a category with the same price there can be more than 3 rows in the output for a particular category. If this behaviour is not the preferred one and you would rather want to see max 3 rows in the output, discarding ties, use `row_number` window function instead.

```
select name, id
from (
  select c.name, p.id, dense_rank() over (partition by c.id order by p.price desc) as rank
  from category c
  left join product_category pc on pc.category_id = c.id
  left join product p on pc.product_id = p.id
) t
where rank <= 3
```